# How do I compare a function so I can triger another function

Tags: swift, function

I have a function that validates fields. Works properly:

```
    //MARK: Validate everything before saving to database
    func validateEverything() {
        checkIfFieldsAreEmpty(textField: accountSetupST2.firstNameTextField, alertMessage: "First name field is empty", view: accountSetupST2.nameView)

        checkIfFieldsAreEmpty(textField: accountSetupST2.lastNameTextField, alertMessage: "Last name field is empty", view: accountSetupST2.nameView)

        checkIfFieldsAreEmpty(textField: accountSetupST2.dobTextField, alertMessage: "You DOB can not be empty", view: accountSetupST2.dobView)

        checkIfTextViewsAreEmpty(textView: accountSetupST2.aboutMeTextView, alertMessage: "You need to write something about your self", view: accountSetupST2.aboutMeView)
}
```

What I am trying to achieve now is to trigger another function if this function returns true:

```
 func saveToDatabaseAndGoToHomePage() {
    print("Save and GO Home")

    if validateEverything() != nil {
        print("Good to go")
    } else {
        print("WRONGGGG")
        // add code to database here
    }

}
```

I've been trying for a few hours but still can't figure out how to do it. 
Practically if all the fields are valid, without errors to trigger another function. Whatever I am trying to compare with, always returns true, even when it finishes and all fileds are validated. So I can not trigger another function.

This is the function for checkIfFields are empty:

```
> extension UIViewController {

    //check if text field is empty
    func checkIfFieldsAreEmpty(textField: UITextField, alertMessage: String, view: UIView) {
        if (textField.text?.isEmpty)! {
            let alertEmptyFields = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertEmptyFields.addAction(action)
            self.present(alertEmptyFields, animated: true, completion: nil)
            view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        } else {
            view.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }

    }
```

Comment: `validateEverything` doesn't return anything...

Comment: your method for  `checkIfFieldsAreEmpty` returns a bool?

Comment: it doesn't  return Bool... I'll place the function in my question in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify this method

```
extension UIViewController {

//check if text field is empty
func checkIfFieldsAreEmpty(textField: UITextField, alertMessage: String, view: UIView) ->Bool {
    if (textField.text?.isEmpty)! {
        let alertEmptyFields = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertEmptyFields.addAction(action)
        self.present(alertEmptyFields, animated: true, completion: nil)
        view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        return false
    } else {
        view.layer.borderWidth = 0
        return true
    }

}
```

and this one

```
    func validateEverything() ->Bool{
           var validTextFields = 0
           validTextFields += checkIfFieldsAreEmpty(textField: accountSetupST2.firstNameTextField, alertMessage: "First name field is empty", view: accountSetupST2.nameView) ? 1 : 0

           validTextFields += checkIfFieldsAreEmpty(textField: accountSetupST2.lastNameTextField, alertMessage: "Last name field is empty", view: accountSetupST2.nameView) ? 1 : 0

           validTextFields += checkIfFieldsAreEmpty(textField: accountSetupST2.dobTextField, alertMessage: "You DOB can not be empty", view: accountSetupST2.dobView) ? 1 : 0

           validTextFields += checkIfTextViewsAreEmpty(textView: accountSetupST2.aboutMeTextView, alertMessage: "You need to write something about your self", view: accountSetupST2.aboutMeView) ? 1 : 0

           return validTextFields == 4
    }
```

then you can do this

```
func saveToDatabaseAndGoToHomePage() {
    print("Save and GO Home")

    if validateEverything() {
        print("Good to go")
    } else {
        print("WRONGGGG")
        // add code to database here
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Works like a charm... Thank you!